# Uniform initialization

Tags: c++, c++11

В С++11 появился новый синтаксис инициализации. Вот что по этому поводу пишет Скотт Майерс в книге Effective Modern C++:

```
class Widget {
public:
  Widget();                                   // default ctor
  Widget(std::initializer_list<int> il);      // std::initializer_list ctor
  …                                           // no implicit conversion funcs
}; 

Widget w1;          // calls default ctor
Widget w2{};        // also calls default ctor
Widget w3();        // most vexing parse! declares a function!    

Widget w4({});      // calls std::initializer_list ctor with empty list
Widget w5{{}};      // ditto
```

Если взять его пример, выкинуть лишнее, и добавить печать в конструктор `Widget`, то окажется что `Widget w4({});` и `Widget w5{{}};` это не одно и то же:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>

class Widget{
public:
    Widget(){

    }
    Widget(std::initializer_list<int> l){
        std::cout << "l.size = " << l.size() << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(){
    Widget w4({}); //l.size = 0
    Widget w5{{}}; //l.size = 1
}
```

[Пример](http://cpp.sh/523lr)

У меня два вопроса:

1. Скотт нас обманывает?
2. Что происходит на самом деле?

Comment: В случае w5 компилятор видимо считает что там в фигурных скобках передан int().

Comment: `std::cout << *l.begin() << std::endl;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Widget(std::initializer_list<int> l)//Это initializer-list constructor
```

Следуя стандарту, он имеет приоритет над другими конструкторами в `list-initialization`.

> Initializer-list constructors are favored over other constructors in list-initialization (16.3.1.7)

```
Widget w4({});
```

Это `direct-initialization`. Инициализатор - пустой `std::initializer_list`.

```
Widget w4{{}};
```

Это уже `list-initialization`. В данном случае `direct-list-initialization`.

Если список инициализации пуст, то выбирается конструктор по-умолчанию.
Если же список инициализации не пуст, то конструктор выбирается в две фазы:

> Initially, the candidate functions are the initializer-list constructors (11.6.4) of the class T and the argument list consists of the initializer list as a single argument
>
> If no viable initializer-list constructor is found, overload resolution is performed again, where the candidate functions are all the constructors of the class T and the argument list consists of the elements of the initializer list.

Начинаем первую фазу "ручного" поиска подходящего конструктора.
В первой фазе все аргументы рассматриваются как один `initializer list`.

Если рассмотреть скобочки в инициализаторе как создание std::initializer_list, то можно ли создать `std::initializer_list<int>`, передав ему `{}`?
Да, можно

```
std::initializer_list<int>{{/*вот он наш единственный int со значением 0*/}}`
```

Всё, подходящий конструктор найден.

То есть в нашем случае

```
Widget w5{{}};
//приведет к такому -->
Widget w5(std::initializer_list<int>{int{}});
```

Или еще примеры:

```
Widget w5{{1}, {2}};//-->
Widget w6(std::initializer_list<int>{int{1}, int{2}});
Widget w7{{1, 2}};//-->
Widget w8(std::initializer_list<int>{std::initializer_list<int>{1, 2}});
```

Старался объяснить как можно проще, поэтому, изложение "своими словами" может быть не совсем точным.

Comment: А вариант `Widget w{{{}}};`? он тоже сработает. Как `initializer_list<int>{initializer_list<int>{int{}}}` или как? Кстати, а `Widget w{{{{}}}};` уже не компилируется...

Comment: @Harry, думаю это `Widget w{{{}}};` компилятор воспримет как `Widget w(initializer_list<int>{int{}});` Первые скобки это вызов конструктора, вторые - список иницаилизации, третьи - конструктор инта

Comment: @Harry `Widget w{{{}}};` даст `Widget w(std::initializer_list<int>{int{{}}})`. Если перенести на обычные переменные, то Вы можете инициализировать так int: `int x{{}}`, но не можете так: `int x{{{}}}`, поэтому вариант `Widget w{{{{}}}};` даст ошибку.

Comment: @Croessmah, Для `w7` получается `l.size = 2`. Так что, думаю, в ответе должно быть так `Widget w8(std::initializer_list<int>{1, 2});`

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb так оно и получается. В моем случае size тоже равен двум. Но запись с дополнительным std::initializer_list я посчитал более понятной. Хотя сейчас в этом сомневаюсь.